# Pulling historical Intraday Volume data from BBG using R

Tags: r, bloomberg

I have a question regarding Pulling intraday historical volume data from bloomberg using "RBBG" package. The way to go in excel is =BDH("IBM US Equity","VOLUME","12/31/2014 9:30:00 AM","12/31/2014 3:30:00 PM","BARTP=T","BARSZ=360","DIR=V","Dts=H").

I do understand that using R, one can pull the data from the trade table as

```
test <- bar(conn, "IBM US Equity","TRADE","2015-02-23 9:30:00.000","2015-02-23 15:45:00.000","375")
```

..but the output I am getting doesnt seem to be correct if the take the volume from this line

```
> test
  time   open  high    low  close numEvents volume
2015-02-23T14:30:00.000 2015-02-23T14:30:00.000 164.23 164.4 162.76 163.28      4079 666782
```

I will really appreciate any inputs on this..